# Along gender, race and ethnicity, and social class lines

Tags: meaning

> Inequality in life expectancy exists within a given society along
>   gender, race and ethnicity, and social class lines.

What does *along gender, race and ethnicity, and social class lines* mean in this sentence, and how can we paraphrase it?

Comment: Along the lines of something: 
*similar to something*.  I think my point is very much along the lines of things that I heard Steve and Ana suggest.http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/along+the+lines+of. Inequality exists in gender, race, ethnicity and social class alike.

Comment: Or here, 'as a function of''.

Comment: @Josh61 I don't think they are necessarily 'alike', in the way they exist. But one could say that *inequality of life expectancy is a function of gender, race, ethnicity, and social class*. Though I am not too sure of the difference between *race* and *ethnicity*. .

Comment: Is it Line Week or what???

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Edwin Ashworth's comment that here "along xxxxx lines" means something like "as a function of." There are a number of ways to rephrase the original sentence if you feel that your audience might not recognize the idiomatic use of "along xxxxx lines." For example:

> Actuarial data indicate[s] that differences in gender, race/ethnicity, and social class within a given society significantly affect life expectancy.

Or:

> Differences in gender, race/ethnicity, and social class have a significant bearing on life expectancy within a given society.

Or:

> Within a given society, a person's life expectancy is, in part, a function of that person's gender, race/ethnicity, and social class.

Or:

> Gender, race/ethnicity, and social class are all factors in a person's life expectancy.